# How do I post a pull request comment using BitBucket REST api 2.0?

Tags: bitbucket-api

Using REST API 1.0, I can do the following

```
POST /api/1.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo}/pullrequests/1/comments
```

What is the equivalent of this in 2.0? 2.0 [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pullrequests-resource-423626332.html) for pullrequests resource states "Finally, you can use this resource to manage the comments on a pull request as well." I don't see a POST for comments similar to 1.0 companion; nor does PUT do anything about comments.

Is posting comments on a PR supported in 2.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know it has been quite a long time since the question was asked, but for people coming to this post:

Bitbucket finally added a way to post comments using their 2.0 API. You check the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-pull-request-id-comments-post) for more info.

And here is an example:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"content": { "raw": "your comment" }}' $URL
```

Comment: Note that, when this question was asked, "Bitbucket" only referred to the cloud product (bitbucket.org). Now there's also Bitbucket Server, fka Stash, which has a different API (tied to the BB Server version).

Comment: True, I am referring to the cloud in this case. Thanks for pointing out @JimRedmond.

Comment: This worked for me after adding this to the headers: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: The url should be: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests or https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D/comments#post

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately pull request comments are currently read-only in 2.0. We are definitely keen to finish that API, but these efforts have been rather under prioritized.

For now, 1.0 remains the only way to mutate PR comments.

Also see: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/32977327/are-you-planning-on-offering-an-update-pull-request-comment-api

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps a line of text in 2.0 API documentation to this effect will save lot of time for future searches.

Comment: is this still the case?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get pull request id using this command :

```
curl -s --request GET --url '{bitbucket_url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_key}/repos/{repo_key}/pull-requests?State=OPEN&at=refs/heads/'${BranchName}'&direction=OUTGOING' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization:Basic {bitbucket_authentication_token}' | sed -n 's/.*"values":\[{"id":\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

And then add the comment using this command :

```
curl --request POST '{bitbucket_url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_key}/repos/{repo_key}/pull-requests/{pull_request_id}/comments' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d {"text": "Add your comment here"} -H 'Authorization:Basic {bitbucket_authentication_token}'
```