# How to create a comment on a Bitbucket pull request

Tags: python, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

How do you programmatically make a comment (preferrably with Python) on a pull request hosted on Bitbucket?

I have a Buildbot server continuously running tests on all my branches hosted on Bitbucket, and after it runs tests for a branch, I want it to check for any pending pull requests and automatically create a comment noting test status (e.g. pass/fail).

[This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pullrequests-resource-423626332.html) and [this](http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/) indicate Bitbucket has a pretty rich API, and even has methods for listing comments, but I can't find any method for creating a comment on a pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [1.0 API documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/pullrequests-resource-1-0-296095210.html#pullrequestsResource1.0-POSTanewcomment) :

> POST a new comment
>   Creates a new comment on an request using the specified content data. The caller must be authenticated and have access to the repository to create an request. 
>   POST https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{pull_request_id}/comments --data "content=string"

Sample for --data is available in above location.

Also, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185166/how-do-i-post-a-pull-request-comment-using-bitbucket-rest-api-2-0) API 2.0 only supports reading of pull request comments and API 1.0 needs to be used to manipulate them.

Comment: This API has been deprecated by Atlassian: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/deprecation-notice-v1-apis/